# shell script input string with regular expression loop values

Tags: regex, bash, shell, brace-expansion

I want to be able to let a user type in :

```
./script.sh server[01-10]type
```

I have got this already working and works with [a-z] or [0-99] or however high numerically it goes. Although really unsure if I have gone about it all the right way and if there are easier ways of doing the same thing.

Wanted to check if there was an easier way of doing something like this and how easy it would be to have multiple wild card inputs like:

```
./script.sh (server|web)[01-10][a-z]
```

where it would then parse for either web01-10a-z or server01-10a-z and list all servers.

Here is what I have so far and admit I need to tidy it up but was thinking let me get it working better before focusing on tidier code calls.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 input=$1;
 if [[ $input =~ \[ ]];then
     s="["
     f="]"
     host_start=`echo $input|awk -F"[" '{print $1}'`
     host_end=`echo $input|awk -F"]" '{print $2}'`
     start=`awk -v a="$input" -v b="$s" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}'`
     fin=`awk -v a="$input" -v b="$f" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}'`
     vals=`expr $fin - $start`
     ((start++))
     ((vals--))
     in1=`echo $input| awk -v s=$start -v f=$vals '{ print substr( $0, s($0),f($0) ) }'`
     val1=`echo $in1|awk -F"\-" '{print $1}'`
     val2=`echo $in1|awk -F"\-" '{print $2}'`
     for index in $(eval echo {$val1..$val2})
     do
         server="$host_start$index$host_end"
         echo "Current server: $server "
     done
fi
```

When I execute this I get:

```
./run.bash apache[9-11]
Current server: apache9 
Current server: apache10 
Current server: apache11 

$ ./run.bash apache[f-k]
Current server: apachef 
Current server: apacheg 
Current server: apacheh 
Current server: apachei 
Current server: apachej 
Current server: apachek 

$ ./run.bash apache[f-k]abc
Current server: apachefabc 
Current server: apachegabc 
Current server: apachehabc 
Current server: apacheiabc 
Current server: apachejabc 
Current server: apachekabc
```

**UPDATED TO THANK EVERYONE**

3 lines does all of above and handles all types I wanted here is how:

```
#!/bin/bash
val=$1;

value=`echo "$val"|sed 's:(:{:g; s:):}:g; s:|:,:g; s/^//;s/$//'`
value=`echo "$value"|sed 's:\[:{:g; s:\]:}:g; s:-:\.\.:g; s/^//;s/$//'`
(eval echo $value)

./test-brace.sh "(server|apache)[0-2][a-c]"
server0a server0b server0c server1a server1b server1c server2a server2b server2c apache0a apache0b apache0c apache1a apache1b apache1c apache2a apache2b apache2c
```

Comment: What is the expected output? The `awk` command for `in1` fails for me, undefined function 's'.

Comment: By the way, are you attempting to replicate brace expansion? `echo {server,web}{01..10}{a..z}`

Comment: 1. Agree that you need to show us more of your usecase, ie. inputs and required output. 2.Are you trying to generate all possible strings, OR only match when a server/resource actually exists? (Edit your question with this info). 3."Wanted to check if there was an easier way ". You likely can capture all of the shell vars `host*, start, fin, etc` and print the output in 1 awk script. 4.That said, +1 for chutzpah! 5.When you figure out how easy is is to get 80-90% of this into 1 awk script, you'll have really learned something. 6. Good luck!

Comment: oh sorry try #!/bin/bash to call script, I will update the original question with output but think the 2nd post from chepner is what I been looking for. Just ran the echo line - that is fantastic Chepner :)

Comment: @chepner: Add that as an answer.

Comment: Updated question with a proper answer thanks to everyone, in the end I did not need to do any removing/adding, although its nice to know how to use posix modifiers properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a script. You just need brace expansion:

```
echo {server,web}{01..10}{a..z}

for s in {server,web}{01..10}{a..z}; do
    echo Current Server: $s
done
```

Comment: thanks, no the reason for the script is due to it being a new requirement for an existing script, hence why I have put it in to one.

Comment: Sorry, I guess "you don't need a script" is a little too strong. You just don't need the portion in the given `if` statement :)

Comment: Thanks again, I have now updated method and made good use of it. https://github.com/vahidhedayati/termssh For anyone who connects to multiple servers and wants an easy way of automating connections - creates terminator(gnome) layouts and launches connection to hosts

Answer (score 3):

Aside from other answers, using forks to `awk` strikes me as a waste of several million CPU cycles. If you just want to delete some subtrings in a shell variable, use these (POSIX) modifiers:

```
$ foo=bar-baz-frob
$ echo ${foo%-*}    # Remove shortest match from the end
bar-baz
$ echo ${foo%%-*}   # Remove longest match from the end
bar
$ echo ${foo#*-}    # Remove shortest match at the beginning
baz-frob
$ echo ${foo##*-}   # Remove longest match at the beginning
frob
$
```

In addition to `*` and `?` accepts `[0-9a-f]` ranges as well, but no `{}` for multiplicity.

If you are willing to trade your shell, the `zsh` can do this with brace expansion:

```
zsh$ setopt BRACE_CCL
zsh$ echo {server,web}{01..10}{a-h}
server01a server01b server01c server01d server01e server01f server01g server01h 
server02a server02b server02c server02d server02e server02f server02g server02h 
server03a server03b server03c server03d server03e server03f server03g server03h 
server04a server04b server04c server04d server04e server04f server04g server04h 
server05a server05b server05c server05d server05e server05f server05g server05h 
server06a server06b server06c server06d server06e server06f server06g server06h 
server07a server07b server07c server07d server07e server07f server07g server07h 
server08a server08b server08c server08d server08e server08f server08g server08h 
server09a server09b server09c server09d server09e server09f server09g server09h 
server10a server10b server10c server10d server10e server10f server10g server10h 
web01a web01b web01c web01d web01e web01f web01g web01h web02a web02b web02c web02d 
web02e web02f web02g web02h web03a web03b web03c web03d web03e web03f web03g web03h 
web04a web04b web04c web04d web04e web04f web04g web04h web05a web05b web05c web05d 
web05e web05f web05g web05h web06a web06b web06c web06d web06e web06f web06g web06h 
web07a web07b web07c web07d web07e web07f web07g web07h web08a web08b web08c web08d 
web08e web08f web08g web08h web09a web09b web09c web09d web09e web09f web09g web09h
web10a web10b web10c web10d web10e web10f web10g web10h
```

I just tried it with bash. It's slightly different:

```
echo {server,web}{01..10}{a..h}
```

Comment: very cool, I had used foo##* in the past and was messing with % but had not understood it too well - it makes full sense now thanks

Comment: @vahid The gory details can be found in your shell manual and of course in the POSIX spec, http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02 Please consider an upvote if you find my answers helpful; thanks!

Comment: Bash has brace expansion as well, so there's no need to switch to `zsh` (although `zsh` does have some very nice features).